# Unable to create Console Application target .NET 5

Tags: .net-5

I am using VS 2019 v16.8.1, I have the option to create WPF(.NET) and similar project to .NET 5 but unable to create a console application target to .NET 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be available on Visual Studio 16.9 per [.NET 5.0 Announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0)

> The templates in Visual Studio 16.8 still target .NET Core 3.1, for console, WPF and Windows Forms apps. The ASP.NET templates have been updated to support .NET 5.0. We will update the templates in Visual Studio 16.9 for the remaining templates.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone wants to do this, there is an alternative way.

1. Create a .NET Core Console Application project.
2. Then change the target framework to .NET 5
   [image]

Comment: Or go into the .csproj file and change it to `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`

Answer (score 0):

Open the .csproj file and change the Target Framework to `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`